# why would I get `no such file to load -- ruby-debug` in production rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake

I have a rake task that looks like so (crontab):

```
cd /data/TheApp/current && bundle exec rake nightly_tasks[3] 
   --trace --silent 2>> /data/TheApp/shared/log/tasks_prod_errors.log
```

It all runs fine in test and dev, but on prod I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- ruby-debug
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in  
   `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in 
        `block (2 levels) in require'
```

OK so I check my gemfile and I have this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug', :platforms => :ruby
...
```

Production env should be ignoring that ruby-debug requirement. So I check my RAILS_ENV and it's correct:

```
$ echo $RAILS_ENV
production
```

On top of that the line that used to require ruby debug in this rake task is commented out. So to me it looks like there's no way bundle exec should be trying to load ruby-debug in prod. Is this maybe something to do with the gemfile.lock? There is an entry for ruby-debug19 in there. But why would my rake task be loading it in that case?

Also, running the command from the command line works fine. Confusing.

Comment: do you have require 'ruby-debug' anywhere in your app?

Comment: @FrederickCheung yeah, but its in my spec tests. Doubt Rake would be using that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rails environment and bundler groups are two completely different things. One doesn't know about the other although they use similar terms in your case

As a workaround, you can use `bundle install --without development test` in production to tell bundler to not install those groups. Alternatively, you can use something like this in your Gemfile:

```
unless ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "production"
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug', :platforms => :ruby
end
```

That expects that you have the environment variable RAILS_ENV set. during your `bundle install` run as well as during your `bundle exec` run (i.e. always).

Comment: You should use `group :development, :test` instead of this strange `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` thingy.

Comment: Yes, that's generally preferred as that is the way most people do (and some deployment scripts expect/support). The env stuff is used most of the time for CI configurations (e.g. for Travis CI or certain Jenkins configs) or for special deployment environments (e.g. Heroku).

Comment: It looks to me like I'm already doing what you suggest in my gemfile -- via my `group :dev etc... `. You're telling me to not install ruby-debug, but I already have that setup in my gemfile and it's been that way for quite some time. The environment I'm deploying too was built after I added that `group` block to my gemfile. In short, I don't think this answers my question.

Comment: @jcollum But you still need to tell bundler that you don't want the group to be used/installed. That's what the `--without` does. Bundler then remembers which gems to *not* load during `bundle exec`. By default, Bundler installs all gems from all groups. And again, Bundler doesn't know about your `RAILS_ENV` and doesn't change anything just because it has a certain value.

Comment: The other question that I have is why this would only be happening via crontab but not by the command line. That tells me that the bundle install isn't the issue (I added that fact to my post a bit ago).

Comment: Still don't think this is the answer. I checked `.bundle/config` and it has this: `BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test`. Pretty sure my Paas provider did that.

Comment: Well then, you probably still have some `require 'ruby-debug'` somewhere in your code (probably some line down in your stack trace)

Comment: @HolgerJust already checked that, the only other place it is is in one of my spec tests. Seems unlikely that rake would be accessing that code.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the “debugger” gem for ruby 1.9.

```
gem install debugger
```